# mySQL: Can I add a calculated column with the sum of all other rows that have that same shared value

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns

I have a data set where each record includes street, zipcode, city, population. I want to find (% of population one zipcode is to the entire city's population) but can't figure out how to group by zip and then add a column that shows total city's population for every zip with that same city.

[Ex Trying to find (Sum_of_City and Percent_of_City)]

Code I tried:

```
SELECT
   city,
   zipcode,
   sum(population) as Pop_Count_ (
   SELECT
      SUM(zSUM) 
   FROM
      (
         SELECT
            SUM(Distinct zipcode) AS zCount 
         FROM
            myTable 
         GROUP BY
            city
      )
      AS A)_ 
   FROM
      myTable_ 
   GROUP BY
      city,
      zipcode;
```

Comment: Use window function to sum the data. `partition by city, zipcode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select city, zipcode, sum(population) as population,
       sum(population) / sum(sum(population)) over (partition by city) as zipcode_ratio
from t
group by city, zipcode;
```

Comment: Doesn't that assume MySQL8+?

Comment: @MatBailie . . . This assumes using a release of MySQL that has been released in that last 2.5 years.

Comment: Yet many sites still don't make it available as part of their platform.  It may not be under the OP's control.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff, I do actually have the latest version of MySQL so Windows Functions work.  I am wondering how this method works too if instead of sum(population) it would be (count(Distinct(neighborhood))... if i also had that field.  (one zipcode to multiple neighborhoods)

Comment: @Verm . . . That depends what you want to do.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're not on MySQL 8 *(in which case you can't use Window Functions)*, here's an alternative approach...  Aggregate twice, then Join...

```
SELECT
  city_zip.city, city_zip.zip_code, city_zip.popluation, city_zip.poupluation / city.population AS ratio
FROM
(
    SELECT city, zipcode, sum(population) AS population
      FROM myTable
  GROUP BY city, zip_code
)
  AS city_zip
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT city, sum(population) AS population
      FROM myTable
  GROUP BY city
)
  AS city
    ON city.city = city_zip.city
```

Or, using a correlated-subquery...

```
SELECT
  city,
  zip_code,
  SUM(popluation),
  SUM(population)
  /
  (
    SELECT SUM(population)
      FROM myTable AS city
     WHERE city.city = city_zip.city
  )
FROM
  myTable AS city_zip
GROUP BY
  city,
  zip_code
```

I suspect the longer code might be faster, though I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried doing the correlated-subquery... it worked as you posted it but the second I tried putting in a "ORDER BY" statement, it timed out (1800s).  @MatBailie

Comment: @Verm - Then try the aggregate and join approach, MySQL may handle correlated subqueries poorly, especially when re-ordering the datasets.  `JOIN` happens before the `ORDER BY` and would likely be less adversly affected by the sorting.

Comment: @Verm - Though your other comments show you have MySQL, so use analytic / windowed functions.